# regex for robots.txt curl output doesn't work

Tags: regex, linux, curl

```
curl -s http://hostname/robots.txt
```

Output needed to parse:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
User-Agent: Mediapartners-Google*
```

I need to take `User-Agent: *` and check it's starting with `User-agent` and ending with `*` 
Tried `curl -s "http://hostname" | grep -i "^User\-Agent:\ \*$"` but I get nothing.

Comment: Your `grep` should have worked. You may try: `grep -i "^User-Agent:.*\*$"`

Comment: This one doesn't work either

Comment: Your `robots.txt` could contain carriage returns, try `grep -i '^User-Agent: \*'$'\r''\?$'`.

Comment: @Freddy right, the carriage return was indeed the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to redirect the output to another file and convert it to unix file.

```
curl -s http://hostname/robots.txt > /tmp/some_file.txt
dos2unix /tmp/some_file.txt
cat /tmp/some_file.txt | grep -i "^User\-Agent\:\ \*$"
```